# If $f(x) = \cos x\cos2x\cos4x\cos8x\cos16x$, then $f’(\pi/4)= ?$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

If $f(x) = \cos x\cos2x\cos4x\cos8x\cos16x$, then $f’(\pi/4)= ?$

Ans: $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Multiply by $2\sin x$ to get $$2^5\cdot\sin x\cdot f(x)=\sin32x$$

Observe that $f\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)=0$

Comment: A good one :-) ${}$

Comment: Multiply by $2^{\color{red}5}\sin x$ is more exact.

Comment: @Bernard, Agreed. But the basic idea was to use double angle formula repeatedly.

Comment: nice one. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that,
in general,
if
$f(x)
= \cos x\cos2x\cos4x\cos8x\cos16x...\cos2^{n-1}x
$,
then,
multiplying by $2^n\sin(x)$
and repeatedly using
$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$,
$2^n\sin(x) f(x)
=\sin(2^nx)
$.

Note that
$f(\pi/4)
= 0
$
if
$n \ge 1$
since
$\cos(\pi/2)
= 0
$.

Differentiating,
$2^n(\sin(x)f'(x)+\cos(x)f(x))
=2^n\cos(2^nx)
$,
so
$\sin(x)f'(x)+\cos(x)f(x)
= \cos(2^nx)
$.

Setting $x = \pi/4$,
and remembering that
$f(\pi/4) = 0$,
$\sin(\pi/4)f'(\pi/4)
=\cos(2^{n-2}\pi)
$
or
$f'(\pi/4)
=\sqrt{2}
$
if $n \ge 3$.