# $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(x2^{-k})$

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate the infinite product $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(x2^{-k}).$$ (Hint : $\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$ )

I have trouble starting out on the issue. Are there someone who is can provide me another hint?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1406039/11619). If $S_M=\prod_{k=1}^M\cos (x/2^k)$ is a partial product, then show that $2^MS_M\sin(x/2^M)=\sin x$

Comment: $$\begin{align}\cos\alpha &= \frac{\sin 2\alpha}{2\sin\alpha}\\
\cos\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2} &= 
\left(\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{2\color{red}{\sin\alpha}}\right)
\left(\frac{\color{red}{\sin\alpha}}{2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)\\
\cos\alpha\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{4} &= 
\left(\frac{\sin2\alpha}{2\color{red}{\sin\alpha}}\right)
\left(\frac{\color{red}{\sin\alpha}}{2\color{blue}{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\right)
\left(\frac{\color{blue}{\sin \frac{\alpha}{2}}}{2\sin\frac{\alpha}{4}}\right)\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align}$$ see the pattern?

Answer (score 3):

I we take for granted that the product converges and denote it as $f(x)$, then by dropping the first factor we see that $f(2x)=\cos x\cdot f(x)$.

Comment: The idea was nice, How to continue?

Answer (score 3):

Another hint : $$\cos(x2^{-k})=\frac{\sin(x2^{1-k})}{2\sin(x2^{-k})}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sin{(x)}=2\sin (x/2) \cos (x/2) = 2\cdot (2 \sin (x/4) \cdot \cos(x/4)) \cos (x/2)$$

Repeat using the formula.