# Given that $f(x) = \cos x. \cos 2x. \cos 4x. \cos 8x. \cos 16x$, find $f'(\pi/4)$

Tags: derivatives

> Given that $f(x) = \cos x. \cos 2x. \cos 4x. \cos 8x. \cos 16x$, find $f'(\pi/4)$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406038/if-fx-cos-x-cos2x-cos4x-cos8x-cos16x-then-f-pi-4

Comment: Hint: $\cos(2x) = 0$ product rule

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Multiply $\sin x$ to the product and utilize the formula:

$$\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ f(x)\sin(x) = \frac{1}{32}\sin(32 x) \tag{1}$$
by the sine duplication formula, hence by differentiating both sides it follows that
$$ f'(x)\sin(x)+f(x)\cos(x) = \cos(32 x)\tag{2} $$
and if we evaluate $(2)$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, since $f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$, we get:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot f'\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(32\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\tag{3}$$
from which $f'\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\color{red}{\large\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \cos x. \cos 2x. \cos 4x. \cos 8x. \cos 16x$$
$$\sin x f(x)=\sin x  . \cos x. \cos 2x. \cos 4x. \cos 8x. \cos 16x$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2 x . \cos 2x. \cos 4x. \cos 8x. \cos 16x $$
$$=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin 4 x . \cos 4x. \cos 8x. \cos 16x $$
$$=\dfrac{1}{8}\sin 8 x . \cos 8x. \cos 16x $$
$$=\dfrac{1}{16}\sin 16 x . \cos 16x $$
$$=\dfrac{1}{32}\sin 32x $$
$$‎\Longrightarrow‎ f(x)=\dfrac{\sin 32x}{32\sin x}$$
$$‎\Longrightarrow‎ f^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{32 \cos 32x . \sin x -\sin 32 x .\cos x}{32 \sin^{2} x}$$
So:
$$f^{\prime}(\dfrac{\pi}{4})=1.???$$

Comment: In the last but one step, its sin^2 x in the denominator

Answer (score 0):

- $$f(x)=\cos\left(x\right)\cdot\cos\left(2x\right)\cdot\cos\left(4x\right)\cdot\cos\left(8x\right)\cdot\cos\left(16x\right)=\prod_{n=0}^4\cos\left(2^nx\right)=\frac{\sin(32x)\csc(x)}{32}$$

So:

$$f'(x)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\sin(32x)\csc(x)}{32}\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{32}\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin(32x)\csc(x)\right)\right]=\frac{\csc(x)\left(32\cos(32x)-\cot(x)\sin(32x)\right)}{32}$$